# Select count of all rows but output rows where age <=30

Tags: php, mysql

```
"id"    "name"      "age"   "address"       "pincode"
"1"     "Peter"     "25"    "1 Elm Street"  "91550"
"2"     "James"     "30"    "2 Elm Street"  "91551"
"3"     "John"      "32"    "3 Elm Street"  "91552"
"4"     "Andrew"    "33"    "4 Elm Street"  "91553"
```

Is it possible to select the count of all the rows here, but display only the ones where age <=30 ?

I need to display only users where age <=30 and provide a link to view other users. The link appears only if there are other users > 30.

I presently do this using 2 selects and php. I looking for a better way to do this, rather than using 2 selects.

**Desidred Output**

```
"id"    "name"      "age"   "address"       "pincode"
"1"     "Peter"     "25"    "1 Elm Street"  "91550"
"2"     "James"     "30"    "2 Elm Street"  "91551"
LINK GOES HERE -> View 2 other users //This is the diff from rows outputted and total rows
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use two queries. One to get the total count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people;
```

And one to select the users under age 30.

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE age < 30;
```

The only way to do this with a single query would be to use a sub-select:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people) AS total_count,* FROM people WHERE age < 30;
```

But this is no less efficient, as you're still executing two statements (logically, you're executing many more statements, as the `SELECT COUNT(*)...` statement would be executed once for every row of output, but your query optimizer ought to optimize that away since they'reall identical), and then you'd have an extra `total_count` column in each row, which you don't want.

Comment: This is what I presently do. No other shortcut way of doing it?

Comment: Not really, these are two queries with two different conditions. There's nothing wrong with doing it like this.

Comment: There is no short cut. There are several long-cuts.  Why do you want a short cut?

Answer (score 0):

You mean, doing all the process that you mentioned in a sql?

I don't think it is possible. The only way will be select all rows and in a loop check if age <= 30.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query:

```
SELECT p.*, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM people WHERE age > 30) as link_count 
FROM people p  WHERE p.age <= 30
```

Comment: As I mention in my answer, this doesn't really provide any advantage, as the DB still has to do two queries, and you have to filter out the duplicate `link_count` column on the client side. It also increases network payload, by sending duplicate data to the client (but reduces network round-trips, which cound theoretically be a concern in some applications).

Comment: I agree, but it does answer his question.

Comment: If I thought it didn't answer the question, I would have downvoted it.

Comment: ;) The REAL correct answer is to re-examine his data model or keep a separate aggregate table for queries.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `people` WHERE `age` <= 30
```

Comment: That's not what he's asking for.